# Custom Gradle Plugin for Android Root Project

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-plugin

In my sample android application,

Root project `build.gradle` contains

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.2.2' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.2.2' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.7.10' apply false
}
```

I am trying to translate that to custom gradle-plugin

```
class CustomGradlePlugin : Plugin<Project> {
    override fun apply(target: Project) {
        target.plugins.withId("com.android.application") {
            it.extraProperties.set("version",  "7.2.2")
            it.apply(false)
        }
        target.plugins.withId("com.android.library") {
            it.extraProperties.set("version",  "7.2.2")
            it.apply(false)
        }
        target.plugins.withId("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android") {
            it.extraProperties.set("version",  "1.7.10")
            it.apply(false)
        }
    }
}
```

When plugin is applied , Gradle throws:

```
> Failed to apply plugin
 > Configuration with name 'api' not found.
```

How can I create this custom gradle plugin?

I tried to apply `org.jetbrains.kotlin.android` before applying another plugin but received the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Have you added the plugin to your build.gradle file?

**build.gradle (From BuilSrc or IncludedBuild)**

```
gradlePlugin {
 plugins {
    create("custom gradle plugin") {
        id = "custom-gradle-plugin"
        implementationClass = "CustomGradlePlugin"
    }
 }

  //other blocks...
}
```

**Apply in yout root build.gradle**

```
plugins {
 id 'custom-gradle-plugin'
}
```

---

---

**OR** You could also do as the following

**build.gradle (From BuilSrc or IncludedBuild)**

```
plugins {
  `kotlin-dsl`
}

gradlePlugin {
  plugins {
    create("custom gradle plugin") {
        id = "custom-gradle-plugin"
        implementationClass = "CustomGradlePlugin"
    }
  }

  dependencies {
     implementation("com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2")
     implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.22")
  }
}
```

**Custom Plugin**

```
class CustomGradlePlugin : Plugin<Project> {

  override fun apply(target: Project) {
     pluginManager.apply {
       apply("com.android.application")
       apply("com.android.library")
       apply("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
    }
  }
}
```